# desktop environment(GUI) not working after downgrading libatk-bridge-dev

Tags: gnome, upgrade, updates, libraries, downgrade

For installing a software I downgraded libatk-bridge-dev. After suspension of the session, when I tried to log into my ubuntu 20.04, the login box kept flickering. After restarting my system, there was black screen with tty1 i.e. teletypewriter. I logged into my system and tried install desktop environment using apt install ubuntu-desktop, it didn't work. It gave some dependencies problem related to gdm3 gnome etc. I tried to manually install them which gave me further dependencies error, 'Some package couldn't be installed. Gdm3: depends: gir1.2-gdm3-1.0 (= 3.36.3-0ubunutu0.20.04.02) but 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.03 is to be installed'. However when I checked the installed version, it was latest yet it gave me same error.